# One htaccess overwriting another

Tags: .htaccess

Apologies if this has been answered before. I've searched everywhere and I just can't find the right solution.

I'm using the opencart rewrite module for better urls:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule sitemap.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've also got a directory (emailer) that I'd like to access as standard. I know the 2 RewriteCond lines above will allow any directory and /emailer works fine.

That is UNTIL i password protect the emailer folder within cPanel, it then creates the following .htaccess in the emailer folder:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "emailer"
AuthUserFile "/home/mywebsit/.htpasswds/public_html/emailer/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Then I suddenly get the page not found error. If I delete this new .htaccess it works fine. I've tried adding the line

```
RewriteEngine off
```

into it but it still doesn't want to know.

What am I doing wrong? I've tackled this before and ended up deleting the original .htaccess file as I was wasting too much time trying to get it working.

Comment: Check your Apache error.log and see if you're getting any error there.

Comment: There's nothing in the error log other than it can't find the 401 not found page.

Comment: File does not exist: /home/mywebsit/public_html/401.shtml

Comment: That means you have custom error handler defined for 401 somewhere.

Comment: But that won't fix my original issue whether I address that or not?

Comment: Yes it definitely will fix original issue. Don't try to brush off this issue, I have seen this happening many times.

Comment: Ah, no. My bad. That 401 error I got was from earlier today, when I saw the page was working (after i deleted the root .htaccess) but didn't bother to log in so I clicked cancel. I've just tried the page now (when I'm getting my original issue) and there's nothing in the error log.

Comment: The fact that it is not even showing your auth dialog means that there is some config/setup issue. Error.log usually has something for this situation.

Comment: It does show my auth dialogue. But only when I get rid of the root .htaccess.

Comment: What if you just comment out your last rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` Do you still get auth dialog?

Comment: If I comment out 'RewriteRule ^([^?]*) /index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]' then I get the auth dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning the rewrite engine *on* in the emailer folder. Turning it on will make any rules in the emailer htaccess have precedence over rules in the parent folder. Since there are no rules in the emailer htaccess file, no rules will get applied:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

then no other rewrite rules.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your DocumentRoot/.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml /index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/emailer/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Done it, and theoretically it should work. But it doesn't. It seems to be the actual RewriteRule line that's conflicting with /emailer/.htaccess. As I said in the comments above, if I comment out the Rule, /emailer works perfectly, but then it doesn't adjust the urls.

Comment: What are current permissions on your `/home/mywebsit/.htpasswds/public_html/emailer/passwd` file?

Comment: The permission for that file is 0644

Comment: I have tried exactly setup described by your got auth dialog. Can you try that in a new browser?

Comment: It does the same in Chrome, IE and Safari. It's perplexing I know, but I'm fairly confident there's nothing I haven't mentioned. I even just tried stripping down all the root .htaccess to only the lines above and still no joy. (there's other things in there that prevent directory listings and direct access to .tpl, .ini, .log files)

Comment: Yes it is quite strange. I recreated my setup as per your description and getting auth dialog without any problem. So most likely there is some config/setup issue on your side.